# How to customize UI or DataTemplate for each item in listView UWP C#

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, user-controls

I have a listView containing different types of items and I need to display them using different elements in UI. e.g. i have children and adult members in listView, and children will not have kids, spouses etc, while adults will have their children, spouses, workplace etc. As far as i know, once i layout structure in XAML using data template, i cannot change it. I created a UserControl for different items, not sure how to use it in ListView when adding items.
Looking for help on how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your scenario, you could try to use [DataTemplateSelector Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector?view=winrt-20348). This class enables you to apply different templates for ListView based on your own logic.

Here are the steps that you need to do to implement this:

1. You will need to create your own `DataTemplateSelector Class`. Then you could declare each template as a property of the class.
2. You need to create an instance of your own `DataTemplateSelector class` in the Resources section of your XAML file. You should create instances of DataTemplate objects and define their layout in the resources section. Then assign these data templates to the **template properties** you declared in the `DataTemplateSelector class`.
3. The final step is that assign the `DataTemplateSelector class` to the **ItemTemplateSelector property** of the ListView.

I've made a simple demo and you could refer to the following code:

**Code behind:**

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public List<int> NumbersList { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        NumbersList = new List<int>();

        for (int i=0;i<10; i++) 
        {
            NumbersList.Add(i);
        }
    }
}

public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ChildrenTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate AdultTemplateent { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        // use your own conditions
        if ((int)item % 2 == 0)
        {
            return AdultTemplateent;
        }
        else
        {
            return ChildrenTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
 <Page.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="AdultTemplateent" x:DataType="x:Int32">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightGray">
            <TextBlock Text="This is Adult Item" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Workplace:NewYork" Margin="5"/>
        </StackPanel>
      
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ChildrenTemplate" x:DataType="x:Int32">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="LightBlue">
            <TextBlock Text="This is Children Item" Margin="5" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" Margin="5" />
            <TextBlock Text="School:DC" Margin="5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplateSelector"  AdultTemplateent="{StaticResource AdultTemplateent}" ChildrenTemplate="{StaticResource ChildrenTemplate}"/>

</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name = "TestListView"
      ItemsSource = "{x:Bind NumbersList}"
      ItemTemplateSelector = "{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}">
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**How it looks like:**

[image]

You could get more detailed information here: [Data template selection: Styling items based on their properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/data-template-selector)